# A feature in Software Product

Tags: software, feature

Can a feature available in a software product patented? For eg, there are various Core Banking Systems and will they be patenting these features? 
Then how are other products able to give the features?

Comment: This is a pretty complex question to answer. Can you be more specific?

Comment: More elaboration would definitely be helpful.